# How to add third party url script and link in the head tag using js?

Tags: javascript

1. URL with script and other with stylesheet to be added in head tag using javascript?
2. How can I add third party script tag in head using javascript and display the code present below after few seconds when page loads completely?

Eg:

```js
<script>
var RequestURL = '';
function onWindowClosed(obj) {
  console.log("callback event : " + JSON.stringify(obj));
  if(obj.event_name === event_name) {
    console.log("successfully returned: " + obj.message);
  } else {
    console.log("unknown-event");
  }
}
var userDetails = JSON.stringify({
  "appId": ",  
  "customerId": "", 
});       
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append elements like scripts or stylesheets using vanilla JavaScript

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", "https://script.example.com/script.js") // Replace with your script link
var head = document.querySelector("head")
head.appendChild(script)
```